# Is it possible to add a new module in Spring framework in a Existing Servlet-Jsp Project

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a requirement to add a new module(on Spring framework) in an Existing Project (on Servlet-Jsp Technology).
I have to convert the Login Authentication module of project in Spring Technology. Is it possible, if Not then What is the other way for it.
Actually that's a live project and very vast.
So we want to slowly migrate the whole project from Servlet-JSP to Spring. 
Plz Guide me regarding that.
Thank you.

Comment: Openly adding your email id will invite you for spams

Comment: Removed the mail id...

Answer (score 0):

Just map spring servlet in your `web.xml` to the separate url and step-by-step move you servlets to spring controllers.

*web.xml*

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In this example all requests with path started from `/spring` will be addressed by `spring-web` meanwhile other servlets should continue to work as before.